# Error message on new farm "Failure checking user access permissions for User Profile Application Proxy"

Tags: user-profile-service

I have created a new SharePoint farm and am getting an error message when I create sub-sites.  The sub-site appears to be created fine (links appear to it in menus) but I also get an error when I attempt to visit it.

The error message says

```
An unexpected error has occurred
```

And, from the log files I'm getting the following error messages:

```
ConnectionString: 'Data Source=XXXXXXXX;Initial Catalog="User Profile Service Application_ProfileDB_c9b5d1154dc648bb82d8394371e0a902";Integrated Security=True;Enlist=False;Asynchronous Processing=False;Connect Timeout=15'    ConnectionState: Closed ConnectionTimeout: 15
Failure checking user access permissions for User Profile Application Proxy 'User Profile Service Application'. Exception: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Cannot open database "User Profile Service Application_ProfileDB_c9b5d1154dc648bb82d8394371e0a902" requested by the login. The login failed.  Login failed for user 'XXXX\XXXX$'.
```

This server has just been joined to the domain too.

How can I check which service account this will be running under?  It should be a domain account, I imagine, if it's attempting to connect to my database server.

Just wondering what else I can check?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you attempt to access the new site, the User Profile Service Application is called resulting in the error. It looks like this service wasn't created correctly.

Try recreating this service according to the following steps:

1. Make a record of any user profile configuration you've made.
2. [Delete the User Profile Service Application](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee721052.aspx#deleteapp).
3. Update to the [latest SharePoint Cumulative Update](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/ff800847) (several fixes were made to this feature after release).
4. [Create the User Profile Service Application](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee721052.aspx#createapp) again. Make sure that you select an application pool running as a domain account (from the error it looks like it's running under a local computer account). One approach is to have an application pool specifically for service applications.

Comment: The application pool that was running the User Profile Service Application was **MYSERVER\NETWORK SERVICE**.  This application pool was also running my site application.  I changed these both to a domain account and it all works fine now.